# How does overloaded global operator new (and variants) work when CRT dynamically linked

Tags: c++

```
void *operator new(size_t s) { ... }

int main()
{
    char *b = new char[256];     // (1) Calls our new
    std::vector<int> v;
    v.resize(128);               // (2) Also calls our new..
    return 0;
}
```

- (1) When compiling this code, compiler uses our overloaded new. OK.
- (2) When compiling this code, compiler leaves implementation of resize() to the CRT - to be linked in at runtime.

**How can the CRTs implementation of resize(), which is linked in at runtime, link back to this module's implementation of operator new**

Edit: To be clear, I'm not asking *how* to do this - I'm stating observed behavior, and asking *how it works*

Comment: Depends on the platform. A lot of ABIs have a provision for "weak symbols", that will be overridden during link / loading. You'll find the `resize` method in turn calls operator new.

Comment: @BrettHale Thanks for your response. I could understand weak symbols working if I statically compiled the CRT in, but its all dynamically linked.

Answer (score 0):

That's going to be a lot of hard work, not practicable at all. You'd have to manually patch the DLLs.

I'm afraid to tell you that this is not really possible, atleast not safely.

Comment: Right, for some reason i was thinking that he is asking how to manually force that on any third party library. My bad. To be fair, that edit came after i already commented on here.

Comment: @FelixLehmann Yes, I added to edit as a result of your comment, to make sure there was no further confusion :)